# Continous decreasing a time in java in format HH:MM:SS

Tags: java, datetime, real-time

I have a to implement a bidding system in a project and on the server, in the auction table, i have a field for start time and end time.

What I am doing is that when a user searches, of course he sees only item whose auction is still open

When the user click on the item, he is bought to a page where he can bid. There I get the interval between the start time and the end time and then i start decreasing the time.

is there any existing code that can be used to decrease a time whose format is in

hh:mm:ss in java

??

Edit:there was an error in the questiom, the time to decrease in the time between the end time and the current time

Comment: Do you really want to decrease a string??? Wouldn't be better decreasing a number and then displaying it in the specified format? Even better don't decrease anything, just show how much time is remaining by computing a difference.

Comment: Probably just a typo, but I think you mean to get the interval between the current time and end time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to decrease the time. You need to show how much time is remaining. i.e. the interval between now and an end time.  Are you using a Java client? Or do you need the code to be in Java script?

EDIT: Say the bid ends at 12:00:00 and the current time is 11:59:20 (40 second to go)  You would calculate the following.

```
long endBidTime = .... // today at 12:00:00
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long remaining = currentTime - endBidTime;
long hours = remaining / 3600000;
long mins = remaining / 60000 % 60;
long seconds = remaining / 1000 % 60;
String remainingText = "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(hours,mins,seconds);
```

You are always calculating the time against a reference time so there is no need to decrement any thing as time progresses in currentTimeMillis() naturally.

Comment: @Puspendu, I think logical thought comes from bitter experience. I do think he was approaching the problem from the wrong direction. I often think that about questions posted to fora.

Comment: hey, in a bidding system, if it remains say 20 seconds, will this 20 seconds remains as it is, won't it decrease, i was just asking about an idea may someone has ever used or who has experience it before because an idea from someone who used it better from an idea on the web

Comment: Yes, I have done this for a bidding website. And the server doesn't say there is 20 seconds left. It tells the client when the bid is over and the client shows how much times is left. Even if the client doesn't update every second, the end of bid time remains the same and the count down clock will be correct whenever it is updated.

Comment: You don't need to decrease the time between the current time and the end time.  This interval should decrease as time progresses. You just need to calculated it periodically and display what it is.

Comment: May be I am getting confused because it's the first time i'm doing this but let's say a client has entered a page and 40 seconds remain for the auction to end, shouldn't the system decrease the 40 seconds every seconds to show the actual remaining time??

Comment: You might say what is the difference?  The difference is that you cannot reliably make something happen every second. This means you may or may not be called every second. If you use a fixed reference point, it doesn't matter if it is called every second because whenever the code is called it will be correct. e.g. it could be called twice a second or once every two seconds and it wouldn't be too inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

I think i will proceed using the following way because i don't want to rely on client time:

-> get the required auction from the server
-> using server time, calculate the remaining time (i.e. Current Server Time- auction end time)

-> Send remaining time to client
-> at client decrease until 0 Second