# Remaining time from current time to 18:30

Tags: java, android, eclipse, time

i want learn remaining time from current time to 18.30

My code is not working:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();    
long endTime = 18:30;
long remaining = endTime - currentTime;
long hours = remaining / 3600000;
long mins = remaining / 60000 % 60;
long seconds = remaining / 1000 % 60;
String remainingText = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,mins,seconds);
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens when you compile and run this code?

Comment: long endBidTime = (); is wrong code, eclipse erroring

Comment: What is the exact error? What are you trying to do in that line of code?

Comment: Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What should the initial value of `endBidTime` be?

Comment: long endBidTime = () in this code, there isn't time(18:30). how i add time in code?

Comment: `long endBidTime = () in this code, there isnt time(18:30). how i add time in code?` I don't understand what you mean. How do you decide what value `endBidTime` takes? Will it always correspond to 18:30? Or can it be a different time than this?

Comment: remaining time finishs at endBidTime. at 18:30.
i didnt add 18:30 in code

Comment: Updated answer with some tips.

Comment: i edited my code, problem : http://i.imgur.com/pAhGxdz.png

Comment: `18:30` isn't a number. It's how us humans represent time. However, Java doesn't know this. You will need to learn how to use the `Date` class as I described in my answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you can write your own `Time` class which manipulates time as hours and minutes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continous decreasing a time in java in format HH:MM:SS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566132/continous-decreasing-a-time-in-java-in-format-hhmmss)

Comment: You have to first find the time in milliseconds at today 18:30 (then find the difference with the current time), see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
long endBidTime = ();
```

As you know, this causes a compiler error. From the comments, you seem to want to set this to 18:30 on the current day. One solution is to use the `Date` object. You will first need to create a `Date` object and set its time to 18:30. See [the javadocs for the `Date` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) for details about how to do this. You will also need to use `Date.currentTimeMillis()` to get the correct value for `endBidTime`.

You have another problem in your code:

```
String remainingText = "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(hours,mins,seconds);
```

This is incorrect and probably gives other compiler errors. Note that the `format()` method is `static`. Even though Java allows us to call `static` method with an instance variable, it is strongly discouraged. Instead, you should use the class name. Also, the format string is the first parameter that `format()` expects. This means you should do the following:

```
String remainingText = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,mins,seconds);
```

Comment: problem is at "long endBidTime = ();"

Comment: @Tahakörkem My answer here is also a problem, although it might be hidden by other problems in your code.

Comment: long endBidTime = ()
in this code, there isnt time(18:30). how i add time in code?

Answer (score 1):

currentTimeMillis() returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_currenttimemillis.htm).
If you want to find the remaining time left till today 18:30. You have to first find the time  in milliseconds at today 18:30 (then find the difference), here is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;

public class timetill1830 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int hr = 18, min = 30, sec = 0;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Now set the time for today 18:30
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hr, min, sec);
    System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    //  Now Print time left till 18:30
    System.out.println("Time in millsec. till 18:30 = "
            + (cal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()));
    formattedTimeLeft(cal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());

}
private static void formattedTimeLeft(long millis) {

    int hrs = (int) (MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) % 24);
    int min = (int) (MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % 60);
    int sec = (int) (MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % 60);
    //int mls = (int) (millis % 1000);
    System.out.println("Time left "+hrs+" hours "+min+" minutes "+sec+" seconds");
}
}
```